# JavaScript сумма значений массива по ключу

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

JS знаю плохо, сильно не пинайте пж. Есть следующий массив:

```
var data = [
  {
      "id": 35,
      "agent_id": 3,
      "first_name": "William",
      "last_name": "Timi",
      "country": "Ukraine",
      "amount": 234.0,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Company Manager",
      "img": "profile-photos/jakob-owens-DQPP9rVLYGQ-unsplash.jpg",
      "is_ftd": false
  },
  {
      "id": 36,
      "agent_id": 6,
      "first_name": "IT",
      "last_name": "IT",
      "country": "Ukraine",
      "amount": 148.97,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Company Manager",
      "img": "profile-photos/mohammad-khaksarmadani-4FDsNcCR8iQ-unsplash.jpg",
      "is_ftd": false
  },
  {
      "id": 37,
      "agent_id": 6,
      "first_name": "IT",
      "last_name": "IT",
      "country": "Ukraine",
      "amount": 148.97,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Company Manager",
      "img": "profile-photos/mohammad-khaksarmadani-4FDsNcCR8iQ-unsplash.jpg",
      "is_ftd": false
  }
];
```

Надо пройтись по массиву, взять все записи с одним ключём agent_id и суммировать все ячейки amount
Помогите пж. Спасибо

Comment: `взять все записи с одним ключём agent_id` это как? взять записи у которых поле  `agent_id` равно какому-то значению? или есть записи у которых отсутсвует ключ `agent_id` и нужно посчитать сумму тех записей, у которых данный ключ присутсвует?

Comment: нужно передавать agent_id функции которая будет брать все amount по данному пользователю и суммировать

Answer (score 1):

Можно так (при отсутствии совпадений функция вернёт `0`):

```js
var data = [
  {
      "id": 35,
      "agent_id": 3,
      "first_name": "William",
      "last_name": "Timi",
      "country": "Ukraine",
      "amount": 234.0,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Company Manager",
      "img": "profile-photos/jakob-owens-DQPP9rVLYGQ-unsplash.jpg",
      "is_ftd": false
  },
  {
      "id": 36,
      "agent_id": 6,
      "first_name": "IT",
      "last_name": "IT",
      "country": "Ukraine",
      "amount": 148.97,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Company Manager",
      "img": "profile-photos/mohammad-khaksarmadani-4FDsNcCR8iQ-unsplash.jpg",
      "is_ftd": false
  },
  {
      "id": 37,
      "agent_id": 6,
      "first_name": "IT",
      "last_name": "IT",
      "country": "Ukraine",
      "amount": 148.97,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Company Manager",
      "img": "profile-photos/mohammad-khaksarmadani-4FDsNcCR8iQ-unsplash.jpg",
      "is_ftd": false
  }
];

function getSum(array, id) {
  return array.reduce(
    (sum, {agent_id, amount}) => sum + (agent_id === id ? amount : 0),
    0,
  );
}
const sum = getSum(data, 6);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Этот вариант мне больше всего подошёл.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```js
function summ(id, arr) {
  return arr
    .filter(({agent_id}) => agent_id === id)
    .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.amount, 0)
}

var data = [
  {
      "id": 35,
      "agent_id": 3,
      "first_name": "William",
      "last_name": "Timi",
      "country": "Ukraine",
      "amount": 234.0,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Company Manager",
      "img": "profile-photos/jakob-owens-DQPP9rVLYGQ-unsplash.jpg",
      "is_ftd": false
  },
  {
      "id": 36,
      "agent_id": 6,
      "first_name": "IT",
      "last_name": "IT",
      "country": "Ukraine",
      "amount": 148.97,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Company Manager",
      "img": "profile-photos/mohammad-khaksarmadani-4FDsNcCR8iQ-unsplash.jpg",
      "is_ftd": false
  },
  {
      "id": 37,
      "agent_id": 6,
      "first_name": "IT",
      "last_name": "IT",
      "country": "Ukraine",
      "amount": 148.97,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Company Manager",
      "img": "profile-photos/mohammad-khaksarmadani-4FDsNcCR8iQ-unsplash.jpg",
      "is_ftd": false
  }
];

console.log(summ(6, data))
```